# How to grab the key from an array when a value matches another value from a string or another array using PHP?

Tags: php

How can I grab a key from an array where a value equals another value for example lets say I have an array and I want to return the key for a value when a match for the value grEen is made. How would I be able to do this using PHP?

```
Array
(
    [147] => ad
    [148] => grEen
    [149] => TRUE
)
```

Answer (score 2):

I bet you are looking for [`array_search`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php):

```
$id = array_search('grEen', $inputArray);
// $id = 148
```

Comment: whit your sample you will become the first key of grEen, not every id

Comment: @silly Indeed. Op wants `to return the key for a value` - one key, isn't it ?

Comment: right, but when `$inputArray = array(1=>'grEen', 2=>'bla', 3=>'greEn');` it will return 1... not array(1,3)

Comment: Don't save the whole world. Op's case doesn't provide duplicated values. He even didn't mentioned about it.

Comment: i don't save the world, i heal the world

Answer (score 0):

```
$inverse = array();
foreach($array as $key => $value) {
    if(false === array_key_exists($key, $inverse)) {
        $inverse[$value] = array();
    }
    $inverse[$value][] = $key;
}
```

now you can become all keys in a array with the value 'search-value'

```
$inverse['search-value']
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually it's quite easy to achieve...
You've got 2 options:

1. If all you want is to pull the first matching key; the use the `array_search()` function
2. If you want all keys that have that value then use the `array_keys()` function supplying the optional parameter (it allows you to specify a `search_value` as the second parameter)

Hope this was helpful?

Answer (score 0):

If you only need to get the id of the first instance found, array_search() is what you want as others have pointed out. If you need ALL instances then preg_grep() can help:

```
$array = array (
    147 => 'ad',
    148 => 'grEen',
    149 => TRUE,
    150 => 'grEen'
);

$greens = preg_grep('/^grEen$/', $array);

$keys = array_keys($greens);
print_r($keys);
```